# How can use android.security.keystore in java program

Tags: java, android-keystore

I want to use `android.security.keystore` APIs in my java program, I tried adding required dependencies(.jar) also I tried to load keystore libraries statically in Java doing this I am able to see the 'AndroidKeyStore' provider in the list of providers but still not able to access APIs for the same.
Can someone please provide me with some info about how can I use androidKeyStore APIs in java program.

Comment: Please take a look here - https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.security.keystore.KeyProperties

Comment: code wise I know how to do it and my code is working as an android app but the problem is when I am using it in normal java code it is not able to get required libraries, I added libraries statically in this case I am able to see 'androidkeystore' provider but not able to use its APIs.